# OAuth using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, oauth

I have already created a web application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. The database was created using SQL 2008.

I use a normal log in where the username and password is entered. NO encryption or security is being used.

To increase the security i found out that OAuth can be used for the purpose of authentication.

What I need to know is whether i could use OAuth for my existing web application. Basically the users who are registerd in my database should only have login access.

Please guide me to implement this.

Your valuable help is much appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth is used for enabling delegated access to protected resources. In other words, that means that you use OAuth when you want to give a third-party access to your data (for example: I want to allow an application to access my facebook data on behalf of me) without giving the third-party your username and password.

OAuth isn't really used for the type of security that it sounds like you are trying to apply to your web application.

You may want to consider Forms Authentication or another native .NET form of authentication -- OAuth is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer !! Is there any specific methodology of form authentication that you could suggest

Comment: I would look into .NET forms authentication. Basically, you'll have a user login through a login page that you create, and then you validate their credentials against your custom Database. Once validated, part of forms authentication is to issue that user a cookie that can be used as their authentication to use your application. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.100).aspx) a good place to start